# Open sets and projections maps in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ metric spaces and $E=E_1\times E_2$ a metric spaces with some metric $d$. Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$  the projections maps of $E_1\times E_2\rightarrow E_1$ and $E_1\times E_2\rightarrow E_2$ respectly, i.e, $$\pi_1(x, y)=x,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\pi_2(x, y)=y;\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall\,\,(x, y)\in E_1\times E_2$$

I know that if $A\subseteq E$ is open then $\pi_1(A)$  is also open in $E_1$ and $\pi_2(A)$  is also open in $E_2$, but the reverse is true? i.e if $\pi_1(B)$  is open in $E_1$ and $\pi_2(B)$  is open in $E_2$ then $B$ is open in $E_1\times E_2$?

Comment: No. Take any open line segment in $\Bbb R^2$ that is not parallel to a coordinate axis.

Comment: @David: Nice one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not true. A slight variation on Cameron Buie's example: let $E_1=E_2=\mathbb{R}$ and let
$$A=\{(x,0):x\in (-1,1)\}\cup\{(0,y):y\in(-1,1)\},$$
i.e., a "plus sign" in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, projected in either direction onto $\mathbb{R}$, we get $(-1,1)$ which is open, but $A$ itself is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Zev as you prove that if $A$ is open in  $E$ then $\pi_1(A)$ is open in $E_1$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $E_1=E_2=\Bbb R,$ and let $B$ be the open unit disk about the origin in $\Bbb R^2$ with the point $\left\langle\frac{\sqrt2}2,\frac{\sqrt2}2\right\rangle$ added. Then $B$ is not open in $\Bbb R^2$, but $\pi_1(B)=\pi_2(B)=(-1,1)$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

---

**Added**: We *can* say (for example) that if $C\subseteq E_1$ is open, then the *preimage* $\pi_j^{-1}(C)$ is open in $E$, since $\pi_1^{-1}(C)=C\times E_2$ for any $C\subseteq E_1.$ However, while we have in general that $$\pi_1^{-1}\bigl(\pi_1(B)\bigr)\supseteq B$$ for any $B\subseteq E,$ we usually don't have equality, so the converse you mentioned doesn't follow from this fact.

Comment: Cameron as you prove that if $A$ is open in  $E$ then $\pi_1(A)$ is open in $E_1$?

Comment: No problem. Hopefully it's clear to you what's going on in the three examples given here. The projection maps basically "cast a shadow" of the sets onto their respective axes. This shadow will "look like" an open set to the axis whenever the set itself is open--that is, for example, $\pi_1(A)$ will be open in $E_1$ whenever $A$ is open in $E$--but these examples suggest that there are many different sets that "cast the same shadows," and not all of them are open, even if the shadows are.

Comment: Adapting David's example, take the open line segment in the plane from $\langle-1,-1\rangle$ to $\langle 1,1\rangle$. This will give the same shadow as the examples Zev and I gave.

Comment: Thanks Cameron I were clear examples. But true that if $A$ is open in $E$ then $\pi_1(A)$ is open in $ E_1 $? My question is how would you do this test?

Comment: As for proving the other direction, what do you know about how the product topology is defined? Depending on the definition, the proof may be almost trivial.

Comment: DEFINITION OF OPEN SETS IN $E_1\times E_2$
A set $A \subseteq E_1\times E_2$ is called open in $E_1\times E_2$ iff it is the union of Cartesian products $G\times H$, where $G$ is open in $E_1$ and  $H$ is open $E_2$

Comment: Exactly. What would $\pi_1(G\times H)$ be? If $\mathcal A$ is any collection of subsets of $E$ and $A=\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal A}B,$ what can you say about the relationship between $$\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal A}\pi_1(B)$$ and $\pi_1(A)$?